# Comparing two string arrays to find matching answers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have had a look at other answers on here as to comparing two string arrays, I have also had some attempts my self looking at comparing with an If statement and .equals() however I am having trouble comparing two strings which contain coordinates.

One string is being retrieved from a database, the other from a set of google maps markers. I've stored them in 2 arrays.

Why wont this print to the console, there are definitely matching entries in both arrays. If i use the search function in the console it finds the 2 matching entries but using the .equals in an if statement wont print it to the console.

The coordinates are printed out like so : (50.371524, -4.13474599999995)

```
var existingMarkers= [];
var databaseMarkers= [];


queryLngLat.notEqualTo("longAndLat", null);
queryLngLat.find({
  success: function(results) {


      alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++ ) {
            databaseMarkers = (results[j].attributes.longAndLat);

          //console.log(databaseMarkers + " DB ");

      //console.log(results[j].attributes.longAndLat);

      //results[j].attributes.Val - gets val of specific marker

      for (d = 0; d < markers.length; d++ ) {

    //console.log("(" + markers[d].getPosition().d + ", " + markers[d].getPosition().e +")");

    existingMarkers  = ("(" + markers[d].getPosition().d + ", " + markers[d].getPosition().e +")");


    //console.log(existingMarkers);
    if (existingMarkers.equals(databaseMarkers)){ console.log("Markersssss");}
       }



    }   


}
```

Comment: Do you get an error on the console? Is `.equals()` defined? It's not a built-in function.

Comment: [20:00:58.421] TypeError: existingMarkers.equals is not a function @ file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/dwilliams4/Downloads/Host/map.js:369

The weird thing is I am using it earlier in my script and getting no error and that comparison works completely fine.

Comment: Are you using any javascript libraries?

Comment: Only things I have are JqueryMobile, JavaScript and Parse linked to my HTML page.

Comment: The gist of the problem is a library you are using has defined `.equals()` and in this particular instance the definition is not included before you are attempting to use it.

Comment: But as far as I am aware, I don't have any libraries. Also this is later in my code than the first time I am calling it.